# Generating Q&As from Cyrillic languages with Deepset Haystack

Tags: nlp, cyrillic, nlp-question-answering, haystack

I'm trying to generate questions and answers based on an uploaded text.

I'm using opensource library [Haystack by Deepset](https://haystack.deepset.ai/) in order to do that as it works great with English texts.

However, with Cyrillic texts like Russian I get chopped words in the generated questions.

I train the model with Russian [SberQUAD](https://huggingface.co/datasets/sberquad) dataset. And then I'm trying to generate Q&As from `Ruslan and Ludmila` poem by Alexander Pushkin.

The answers seems OK mainly, but the questions are really mix of syllables.

Here is my code:

```
converter = TextConverter(remove_numeric_tables=False, valid_languages=["ru"])
doc = converter.convert(file_path='pushkins.txt', meta=None)[0]

preprocessor = PreProcessor(
    clean_empty_lines=True,
    clean_whitespace=True,
    clean_header_footer=False,
    split_by="word",
    split_length=100,
    split_respect_sentence_boundary=True,
)

docs_default = preprocessor.process([doc])
document_store.write_documents(docs_default)
question_generator = QuestionGenerator()
reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path='cointegrated/rubert-tiny', use_gpu=True)
reader.train(data_dir=data_dir, train_filename="train-v1.1.json", dev_filename="dev-v1.1.json", use_gpu=True, batch_size=16, n_epochs=1, save_dir=data_dir) 

qag_pipeline = QuestionAnswerGenerationPipeline(question_generator, reader)
output_data = []

for idx, document in enumerate(tqdm(document_store)):
    print(f"\n * Generating questions and answers for document {idx}: {document.content[:100]}...\n")
    result = qag_pipeline.run(documents=[document])
    output_data.append(result)
    print_questions(result)
    print("---")
```

The output is just some mix of Russian syllables and English words:

```
Generated pairs:
 - Q: What is какат а доер мое?
      A: свои
      A: дети
      A: согласен Скакать за дочерь
 - Q: What удет не нарасен?
      A: подвиг
      A: моих
      A: княжной
 - Q: What was орестн ени?
      A: княжной
      A: княжной
      A: полцарством
 - Q: What did оскликнули свои седлаем?
      A: Сейчас коней
      A: жены
      A: «Я!» — молвил горестный жених. «Я! я!» — воскликнули с Рогдаем Фарла
 - Q: рад вес иедит мир.
      A: «Сейчас коней своих седлаем; Мы рады
      A: ъ
      A: лцарством прадедов моих
```

Comment: `QuestionGenerator` uses `valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg` as default model, have you tried using `model_name_or_path=cointegrated/rubert-tiny` for that too?

Comment: Also seems like https://huggingface.co/cointegrated/rut5-base-multitask (ask task) and https://huggingface.co/nbroad/mt5-base-qgen look like your best bets for Russian Question Generation. Also check some of the new multilingual models. If you're ok using non OS models gpt3.5 should be the great too.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza You are right! Thank you. Do you want to propose it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QuestionGenerator` uses `valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg` as default model.

Since you're using `FARMReader` with `cointegrated/rubert-tiny` you must use a compatible model for `QuestionGenerator`. Compatibility in this case is only in terms of language of the model.

```
question_generator = QuestionGenerator(model_name_or_path='nbroad/mt5-base-qgen')
reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path='cointegrated/rubert-tiny', use_gpu=True)
```